# Color switching button with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have this example code to highlight specific cells of a table. Is there a way to switch colors or use multiple colors at the same time?

I am trying to make a button to switch the color of hightlighting. By default when a value is selected, it is highlighted in green color. I would like to have a button so that when I click, my next selection will be a different color. So every time I click this button, the next selection will be a different color. is there a simple way to achieve this?

Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/g28xasd7/ and my code:

```
$('.selector').each(function() {
    $(this).on('click', check);
});

$('.all').each(function() {
    $(this).on('click', all);
});

function all(event) {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $("input:checkbox:not(:checked)", $(this).parents('form')).not(this).prop("checked", "checked");
    } else {
        $("input:checkbox(:checked)", $(this).parents('form')).not(this).prop("checked", "");
    }

    //$('.selector').prop("checked", this.name === "SelectAll");

    check(event);
}

function check(event) {
    var checked = $(".selector:checked").map(function() {
        return this.name
    }).get()
    $('td').removeClass("highlight").filter(function() {
        return $.inArray($(this).text(), checked) >= 0
    }).addClass("highlight")
    if ($(this).is(".selector"))
        $('.all').not(this).prop("checked", false)
}
```

Or is there another way to change the color?

Comment: Suggestion: Fix the formatting on your code to be 100% uniform, and reduce it if there's anything there you can get rid of.

Comment: Anthony Astige done. https://jsfiddle.net/max33/g28xasd7/  I cleaned the css. it was unpolished. now there is no css.

Comment: @Max there is no use of the `all` class anywhere, so for this question the all(event)  and .all each methods are irrelevant, so please remove them

Comment: edwardmp https://jsfiddle.net/max33/p05yn7Lr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention to the IDs, they must be unique. Instead of class I used directly the background-color.

My snippet is:

```js
$(function () {
  $('.selector').on('click', function(e) {
    var checked = this.name;
    var selectedColor = '';

    if (this.checked) {
      selectedColor = $('#nextColor').val();
      
      // instead if you need a random color generated automatically:
      // selectedColor = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
    }
    $('td').filter(function() {
      return this.textContent == checked;
    }).css('background-color', selectedColor);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
    <div id="sidebar1">
        <body class="twoColLiqLt">
        <div id="container1">
            <div id="sidebar11">
                <h3>Choose a color: <input id="nextColor" type="color" value="#9ac99d"> Parameters:</h3>

                <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="A" class="selector"/>A</label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="B" class="selector"/>B</label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="12" class="selector"/>12</label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="Y" class="selector"/>Y</label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="Z" class="selector"/>Z</label>

                </form>

                <form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="">

                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="K" class="selector"/>K</label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="J" class="selector"/>J</label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="M" class="selector"/>M</label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="T" class="selector"/>T</label>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="N" class="selector"/>N</label>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="mainContent">
            <h3 align="right">&nbsp;</h3>

            <div>
                <table width="200" border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <td>A</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>M</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>K</td>
                        <td>J</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>B</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td> 12</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>12</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>Y</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>M</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>T</td>
                        <td>K</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>Z</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: gaetanoM You were a great help, thanks. I have a question. when I change one of the values say "x" to  a double digit number say "12", the code doesn't work. can you suggest me what I should do or what am I missing, please? if that is not too much. thanks.

Comment: gaetanoM you can see it here. https://jsfiddle.net/max33/k4nfkx49/ it is strange.

Comment: @Max Sorry for the delay. Snippet updated with table containing the string 12 instead of X. Adjust your javascript according to the updated snippet. Let me know.  Thanks so much.

Comment: @Max I forked your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aq03jL7q/1/ this is the corrected one.

Comment: Thanks really, it works perfectly. There was no way I could do that.

Answer (score 0):

This is way to go, you can improve your code using this function.

```
$('.selector').each(function() {
  $(this).on('click', check);
});
function getRandomColor() {
        var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
        var color = '#';
        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
            color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
        }
        return color;
    }
function check(event) {
  var checked = $(".selector:checked").map(function() {
    return this.name
  }).get()
  $('td').css('background-image', 'none').filter(function() {
    return $.inArray($(this).text(), checked) >= 0
  }).css('background-color', getRandomColor());
  if ($(this).is(".selector"))
    $('.all').not(this).prop("checked", false)
}
```

Comment: I updated the code and your fiddle.. This way to go you have to do some other changes in your code to reach to solution.but this is the way you can get random color.

Comment: Yasin Uzun can you share your fiddle, please? I can't see it.